# PHP blank field in </attribute>

Tags: php, xml

I´m wondering how to return a empy value into my "attribute" in case the final user doesn´t fill in the form field called "name" and leave it blank.

**My actual code:**

```
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['name']);
$domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
$domAttribute->value = 'Name';
$domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);
```

**Desired ouput in case of empty input in the form field "name":**

```
<attribute domainname="Name"></attribute>
```

**Current output based on the actual code:**

```
<attribute domainname="Name"/>
```

As you can see, it´s not being completed by `</attribute>` but just `/>`

Any clue?

Comment: Although not visually identical, these two examples are technically identical.

Comment: @WebCode.ie So, technically speaking, is it gonna work fine when import the .xml file?

Comment: @Wager - Yes should do.

Comment: @WebCode.ie thank you for now.

Comment: Often referred to as a *self-closing tag* in case you were wondering...

Answer (score 2):

You can use const **LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG**

```
<?php
$domDocument = new DOMDocument;
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute');

$domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
$domAttribute->value = 'Name';

$domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);

echo $domDocument->saveXML($domElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG), PHP_EOL;
```

[image]

http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-noemptytag

Comment: I did use the method `$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($domDocument->saveXML($domElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG)));` but it´s still the same

Comment: Also, `echo $domDocument->saveXML($domElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);` did not work.

Comment: I updated my answer with full example. As you can see, it working

Comment: It´s still not wortking for me, because I depend on User´s input `('attribute', $posted_data['name']) `.  I can not just delete the _$posted_data_ as per your example.